# Turn a panel into a circle in C# Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a basic soccer game in C#, and ive almost completed the field except for the various arcs and circles that are fairly important in the game, especially to set the bounds the computer's players cannot pass while their teammate/opponent is lining up for the kick.
So, all the methods I've tried havent worked because apparently I'm using fields like types, but I'm copying the code exactly. But I don't think its very important to show the buggy code, for a start I deleted it and I'd like the circles to be there permanently, not from when debugging starts.
So this is what I need: panels with round borders that stay round, and a way to put it in my code, which I'll post if necessary. Visual Studio C# Express 2010.
All help appreciated, thanks

Comment: You should show us the buggy code so we can help.  Drawing cirlces on a Control is a lot easier than trying to make some sort of Panel with round borders.

Comment: You should also explain if you are using WPF or Windows Forms.

Comment: I'm using Windows Forms. If you could show me how to draw circles/arcs onto a panel that would be even better, all that matters is that they can deal with a MouseEnter event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to draw a circle on a panel is to inherit from `Panel` and override the `OnPaint` method. In this method you would call `DrawEllipse` on the `Graphics` object gotten from the event args. On point of interest is that the size is set to Width-1 and Height-1. This stops the right and bottom of the circle from dissapearing out of the Panel control.

One enhancement I have put in this code is to constrain the width & height in the `OnResize` method, this ensures your panel is always a circle, in oppose to an Ellipse (which can have different width and height). Simply drag this control onto a windows form and have a play in the designer.

```
public class CirclePanel : Panel
{
    public CirclePanel()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, 0,0,this.Width-1,this.Height-1);
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width = this.Height;
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've done that, but nothing has happened :(. I think it probably lies in the public CirclePanel having nothing inside it. I have 8 panels I need to draw arcs on, would I need to put their names in here? Sorry if this is annoying
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Pen mypen;
        Color mycolor=Color.Red;
        Graphics mygraph;

        int xloc = 50, yloc = 50;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mygraph = CreateGraphics();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        float x = 270, y = 0.5f;

        int xmover = 100, ymover = 48;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            mygraph.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), xloc, yloc, 102, 102);
            mygraph.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), xmover++, ymover++, 4, 4);
            mycolor = this.BackColor;
            mygraph.DrawPie(new Pen(mycolor), xloc+1, yloc+1, 100, 100, x-1, y);
            mygraph.DrawPie(new Pen (Color.Red), xloc + 1, yloc + 1, 100, 100, x++, y);
            mygraph.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(mycolor), xmover-1, ymover - 1, 4, 4);
            mygraph.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red), 100, 50, 5, 5);


        }
    }
}
```